# Magento 1.9 When is inventory subtracted and where to edit it in code?

Tags: magento-1.9, inventory

In Magento, when an order is successful placed. The item will be subtracted from the stock. I want to know when is this happened, and if I want to edit the logic to this, which file should I look at?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Magento subtracted qty after **checkout_submit_all_after** event fire.

Open **app/code/core/Mage/CatalogInventory/Model/Observer.php**

Check following method

```
/**
 * Subtract qtys of quote item products after multishipping checkout
 *
 * @param Varien_Event_Observer $observer
 * @return Mage_CatalogInventory_Model_Observer
 */
public function checkoutAllSubmitAfter(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)
{
    $quote = $observer->getEvent()->getQuote();
    if (!$quote->getInventoryProcessed()) {
        $this->subtractQuoteInventory($observer);
        $this->reindexQuoteInventory($observer);
    }
    return $this;
}
```